# При клике по одному из div из набора div'оv с одинаковым классом в JS попадает самый первый

Tags: jquery

Добрый день. Испытываю небольшое затруднение. Есть HTML-сайт http://samurai.spb.ru/. Там реализован горизонтальный скроллинг различных товаров (неправильно это, но что есть то есть, просят именно так), и у каждого товара есть кнопка "Заказать эту дверь", при клике по которой открывается форма обратной связи - в первое поле которой с помощью JQuery идёт автоподстановка названия конкретной двери (и на первом товаре это отлично работает).

Реализовано это так - в главном большущем файле index.html в сегменте у каждого товара эта кнопка создаётся при помощи нехитрого кода:

```
<div class="open_modal"  name="1. Входная дверь Самурай «Коричневый»" ><p>Заказать эту дверь</p></div>.
```

Соответственно, у других дверей "name" будет например "Самурай Серый" или еще что-нибудь)

А в JS-скрипте написано:

```
$('.open_modal').click(function (e)
{
 e.preventDefault();
 $('.popup, .overlay').css({'opacity':'1', 'visibility':'visible'});  //Делаем видимой popup-форму обратной связи
 var door_name = $('.open_modal').attr('name'); //Получаем название товара
 $('#tovar_field').val(door_name); //Вписываем в поле ввода формы название товара
 });
```

На первом товаре всё отлично работает - а на 2-м и 3-м вместо их "name" упорно подставляет "name" из первого товара "Входная дверь Самурай Коричневый".

Почему JQuery для каждого последующего  при клике по нему захватывает атрибуты из самого первого div-а, а не из того по которому кликнули? Как это исправить, чтобы при клике 2-го div'а брались именно ЕГО атрибуты?

Comment: Потому что по умолчанию берется первое вхождение. Нужно вместо селектора использовать `$(this)`

Comment: Ок, заработало! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Потому что вы не правильно обращаетесь к элементу на котором сработало событие. Вы делаете это так

```
$('.open_modal').attr('name'); //Получаем название товара
```

То есть берете все элементы с классом `open_modal`. Отсюда и возврат атрибута от первого элемента с таким классом.

Вам надо использовать обращение $(this) внутри функции.

```
$(this).attr('name'); //Получаем название товара
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё получилось!